# How to re-ask an old question?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know whether there has been progress in the last five years on the 2011 question [H^4 of the Monster](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69222/). Given the discussion there (and also given what else I know of the field), it seems plausible that there has been progress. Is there a way to bump that question to the front page? Should I post a new question asking "has there been progress since 2011"?

Comment: If you can state briefly what more of an answer you hope for, you can put a low bounty on it.  I would suggest that and contacting some of the other members before doing an edit or reasking using a new question.  Gerhard "Here The Points Do Matter" Paseman, 2017.04.11.

Comment: How do bounties work when an answer is already accepted?

Comment: I imagine the same way as when an answer is not accepted.  I just went to click on "start a bounty" . Gerhard "Seems Simple Enough To Me" Paseman, 2017.04.11.